# Dual Booted PC skips Boot Menu, directly boots Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I couldn't find Grub Menu. It directly goes into Linux. I seriously need windows. Please help me someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well... not much information but I'll give it a try... **WARNING** Lot of assumptions ahead.

1. Windows is configured to use UEFI
2. Linux is Ubuntu and configured to use UEFI

Open Terminal and execute the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

Open the Boot Repair application and select Advanced Options -> Other Options tab -> Repair Windows boot files.
Boot flag should be on the same partition where Ubuntu is.

[image]

If that doesn't work please refer to the following answer from [James Ray](https://askubuntu.com/a/947628)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you installed both Linux Mind and Windows 10 in UEFI mode, holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting should get you directly to GRUB. If that doesn't work the try again with <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

There are 2 ways to permanently fix this:

**1. The easy way**

- Install [Grub Costumizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

- Open Grub Costumizer (Enter your password if requested)
- Go to Tab `General Settings`
- In `Visibility` submenu enable `show menu` and `look for other operating systems`
- On the top left corner click "Save" to save the configuration and update Grub
- Reboot. You should now be greeted by GRUB without any interventions

**2. The hardcore way**

- Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- Find the line that says `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and comment it out by adding a "#" at the beginning of that line.
- Also find the line that says `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=""`
- Write `menu` in to the quotes (if that's not already the case), so now it says

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
```

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>y</kbd> to save and exit.
- Update grub by using:

```
sudo update-grub
```

- If you get the error `command not found` use

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

- Reboot. You should now be greeted by GRUB without any interventions